# Disparate performance between SQLite command-line client and SQLite library for the same query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've been working on a performance-critical application, and one of the queries involved has this structure (names have been changed, but nothing else):

```
SELECT x.* FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT c_a, c_b, c_c
    FROM b
    UNION ALL
    SELECT c_a, c_b, c_c
    FROM c
) AS x
ON a.c_a = x.c_a
WHERE a.c_d = ?
ORDER BY a.c_a
```

I have run `EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN` on this query and all indexes seem to be used appropriately.  Using the command-line client, this query completes in about 0.75 seconds.  This is about what I would expect given the amount of data in the database.

However, the same query executed through the SQLite library gives dramatically different behavior.  Profiler data shows that for *one* execution of this query, the time spent in the `sqlite3_step()` function is about 120 seconds.  This sub-second query is taking two minutes with the library, and I have absolutely no explanation as to why.

The database file being operated on in both cases is byte-for-byte identical.

The SQLite library is version 3.7.2, and the command-line client is version 3.7.13.  I don't know if this may be a factor, but it seems unlikely to me.

---

Things I have tried:

- Vacuuming the database.  There was no statistically-significant improvement in performance.
- Changing journal modes.  I switched from using a rollback journal to WAL for reasons not related to this question, but this also did have any statistically-significant impact on performance.

Comment: Have you tried another library yet?

Comment: Another library what?  A different, compatible SQLite implementation?  A different embedded database?  How would this help resolve a SQLite-specific problem?

Comment: Maybe there's some sort of bug in the implementation that you are using. You have to pin point the problem further. Without your actual database and code, we'd only be guessing here..

Comment: Which "other library" would you suggest that I use?

Answer (score 1):

To provide closure for observers and participants, upgrading to SQLite 3.7.13 appears to have solved this problem; now 1.5 seconds are spent in `sqlite3_step()` which is obviously a dramatic improvement.  3.7.2 appears to have some bug or missing optimization that inflated the time required to execute the query.

Other instances of weird behavior also included delays that were a multiple of 60 seconds.  This may be indicative of a lock-related bug in 3.7.2 (See [EthanB's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12078605/501250)) that has since been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Is the command-line client locking the database when the SQLite library tries to run? I seem to recall 60 seconds being a SQLite query timeout (which I ran into with an NHibernate client).

Comment: The command-line client is closed.  This happens even after a fresh reboot of the server; no other process has the database open.  However, the timeout scenario is an interesting one.  I will do some digging and see if perhaps this is occurring somehow... my process *should* only be opening one handle to the database... who knows.  However, the query does succeed -- I do not get SQLITE3_BUSY or any other error that would indicate a timeout has occured.